# Stop and start SolrCloud

Tags: solr, nosql, solrcloud

I start working in SOLR Cloud in my local laptop. I started my solr cloud by command:

```
cd C:\dev\solr-6.5.0
.\bin\solr -e cloud
```

I given all configurations. And given collection name as 'MyCollection'

I closed, And I am tring to restart. I used same command

```
cd C:\dev\solr-6.5.0
.\bin\solr -e cloud
```

It is asking all options again.

How to restart with my previous options?

I say in the documentation.

```
bin/solr -e cloud -noprompt
```

But it saying it will take all default setting. Then my previous selected options will be gone.

I saw restart commands on node wise one in the documentation.

How can I restart my solrcloud with my all previous settings?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try restart command in solr, but we are solving that problem by having the custom script file which will have all the needed configuration as like this,

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stopping Solr now ..."

bin/solr stop -all

echo "Starting Solr now!..."

bin/solr start -force -c -a  "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=****"
```

This is shell script since we are using the linux, we have done like this and we are using the same script file to restart with the same property always.

Another way is directly changing the `solr.in.sh` file:

`solr.in.sh` file will be available in the bin directory for the installation location of solr, when we can add our default configuration directly which will be taken care when we are starting the processor.